# E-mail all - Character limit issue

Tags: html, outlook, mailto, email-client

Is there anyway to get around the maximum character limit on "mailto:"? the requirement is to have an option send email to all the persons returned by search criteria. So, on the controller side, after the person objects are gathered, I have iterated through them all to get a "To" string with all their emailids appended. But the issue is that, on the view side

```
<a href="mailTo:${toList}">Email all Returned results</a>
```

won't work when the toList size exceeds certain limit(2083 for IE, apparently). So is there anyway to get around this limit? My requirement is not to send email to the results, just open up the e-mail client for users and they can decide what to have in body and whom to remove from the list etc..

Comment: I just hope you don't want to send more than 2000 emails? Or are you talking about stringlength of 2083?

Comment: string length of 2083..the String in "mailto:String"

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's no way to "get around" that IE limit (more info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427 ).

If you really need to send so much emails at once switch to a server-side solution (and it will be far better even for the privacy) OR just ask the users to use another browser.